# Override @override with AOP

Tags: java, aop, micronaut

I'm giving AOP a try for the first time. I want to do AOP on the @Override notation to write logs. It seems to be almost working but:

1. I have to import my own Override class in every class. Is this normal? I thought that it would *magically* go through my @Override decorator first and then through the Java one.
2. I have this very weird behavior where depending on the endpoint that I call first, it keeps working after or it only works for this one endpoint. Say, I have /a and /b, if I call /b first, it shows my logs, then I'll call /a and it won't show anything, if after that I call /b it will show logs. However, if I call /a first, it works, then I call /b and it works, and it just keeps working for all of them. It makes no sense to me.

This is my OverrideInterceptor:

```
@Slf4j
public class OverrideInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor<Object, Object> {

  @Override
  public Object intercept(MethodInvocationContext<Object, Object> context) {
    String prettyMethod = context.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName() + "." + context.getName();
    log.debug("{} with params {}", prettyMethod, context.getParameterValueMap());
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Object result = context.proceed();
    long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
    log.debug("Execution of " + prettyMethod + " took: " + (end/1000) + "ms.");
    return result;
  }
}
```

And my annotation:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Around
@Type(OverrideInterceptor.class)
public @interface Override {

}
```

Both classes are in the package: package com.time.infrastructure.config;

And I'm using this @Override annotation in packages under com.time.infrastructure.db, com.time.infrastructure.rest, com.time.application.repository, etc.

Comment: Which package is your `Override` interface in? It's not visible on the annotation snippet.

Comment: @ollitietavainen I've added it to the answer! package com.time.infrastructure.config; for both classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point 1: The built-in `@Override` annotation is a normal `@interface` - it resides in the `java.lang` package. What you've done here is that you've created a custom annotation with the name `Override` in the package `com.time.infrastructure.config`, which has nothing to do with `java.lang.Override`. So in that sense, it's "normal", but it's probably not doing what you think. You can't subtype annotations in Java, unfortunately.

Comment: So I can't override @Override?

Comment: Technically you could provide a replacement Override to the same `java.lang` package in your project, but that is a bad practice and you should avoid doing it unless you really must.

Comment: Besides, there is no way to intercept the original `@Override` annotation via AOP either because it is invisible during runtime. It has `SOURCE` retention as is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html). P.S.: Using the same class name for your own annotation as one of the most frequently used JRE annotation types is like code obfuscation. Just don't do it.

Comment: @kriegaex I see. I wanted to expand on it... But yeah, I think my #2 issue was related to me using the name 'Override'. When I put a different one, it works perfectly.

Comment: Well, technically you could also use compile-time aspect weaving (depending on the AOP framework used). But the point about code obfuscation is really important - you don't want to add secret meanings to a common built-in annotation.